# Swift3 assigning values to nullable object

Tags: swift

```
if project == nil {
    project = Project()
}

project!.title = titleInput.text
project!.description = descInput.text
project!.field1 = field1.text
project!.field2 = field2.text
project!.field3 = field3.text
project!.field4 = field4.text
project!.field5 = field5.text
```

In the above code, before assigning values to object, it generates project instance if the project is nil. So we can sure the project never gonna be nil, but the below of that, it still uses **!** (project!.xx) so it looks ugly.

How can I make it cleaner?

[Edit]
The project is class variable, and the project could be nil or could be not.
So, I need to check before creating the instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let project = project ?? Project()

project.title = titleInput.text
```

The nil coalescing operator `??` evaluates to the non-nil value of the expression or else the value that follows, which may or may not be Optional.

Update for edit: The cleanest approach depends a little bit on the context of this code, but I might still use a similar construction:

```
let project = self.project ?? Project()

project.title = titleInput.text
...

self.project = project
```

I begin to wonder though, should this class property really be an `Optional`? For that matter, should it really be a property?

Comment: I delete my request for an explanation because you already added it as I hit add comment. :-) Good answer!

Comment: This doesn't work since it creates a new variable different from the `project` class property

Answer (score 3):

To create an instance if it's `nil` looks like a lazy instantiated property.

```
if project == nil {
    project = Project()
}
```

is pretty *objective-c-ish*,  in Swift there is a more sophisticated way, the `lazy` keyword is not needed because class properties are instantiated lazily by default.

```
static var project : Project = {
    let proj = Project()
    proj.title = titleInput.text
    proj.description = descInput.text
    proj.field1 = field1.text
    proj.field2 = field2.text
    proj.field3 = field3.text
    proj.field4 = field4.text
    proj.field5 = field5.text
    return proj
}()
```

You can also use

```
static var project = Project()
```

or if `Project` has reference semantics even

```
static let project = Project()
```

on the top level of the class – the property is lazily instantiated as well –  and assign the property values somewhere else.

In all cases the instance is not created until it's accessed the first time and it's created **once**.